# How do I get the value from the UWP DatePicker control?

Tags: uwp

I am using a couple of DatePickers in my UWP app and am unsure how to get the current value from it. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property you're looking for is Date.

If you've got your DatePicker in your XAML like this

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker" />
```

And want to access the date in the code-behind, you can do that like this

```
var date = this.DatePicker.Date;
```

You could also listen to the DateChanged event like this

```
this.DatePicker.DateChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            var changedDate = e.NewDate;
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

Date member is not DateTime

so assume datePicker1 is your datePicker,

```
<DatePicker x:Name="datePicker11" />
```

you can get selected value like this:

```
DateTime firstDate = datePicker1.Date.DateTime;
```